# Duda basica acerca de DNS e IP dinámica

Tags: dns

tengo una dudas acerca de DNS e Ip dinamicas.
Tengo montada una web en un servidor gratuito (Hostinger) y con una base de datos que el mismo servido ofrece.
Bueno mi web envía un dato hacia un modulo electrónico que esta en mi red local (este configurado como servidor) desde la pagina web montada en el servidor. Ahora como mi router va cambiando la IP publica cada cierto tiempo, debo actualizar la dirección donde debo apuntar el envió del dato en mi pagina web.
Un compañero de este foro me comento acerca de utilizar un servicio como NO-IP....Estuve investigando de acerca de eso y al parecer debo mover todos los archivos de mi web hacia ese host y ademas hacer nuevamente la base de datos.
Entonces mi pregunta es:
¿Debo mover si o si los datos que están en mi actual host (Hostinger) o se puede realizar alguna conexión entre el host que estoy utilizando (Hostinger) y el host en NO-IP para que no mueva todos los archivos de mi web hacia el nuevo host?

Cualquier información me sera de utilidad 
Saludos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Noip, **no** es un servidor de archivos, es un servidor de nombres, por lo tanto,
2. **No** tienes que mover tus archivos actuales, de hecho,
3. Solo tienes que hacer un cambio en tu sitio,
4. En lugar de escribir la IP de tu equipo local, escribirás el nombre de tu servidor que selecciones en noip.
5. Así que tus sitio remoto siempre encontrará tu servidor local, porque quien resuelve la dirección es noip
6. Solo tienes que actualizar tu ip en noip, cuando tu router te asigne una nueva, pero
7. Hay programas que hacen eso automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias compañero me resolviste una gran duda para mi.

Comment: Segui comentario y me funciono perfectamente.
ahora solo tengo una ultima duda.....Descargue de NO-Ip un programa que me va actualizando la ip pero ese programa esta corriendo en mi computador si apago mi PC ese programa no actualizara mi ip, entonces si quisiera enviar ese dato desde mi web desde otro pc y el programa no me esta actualizando mi ip en el host.
¿Como podría solucionar ese problema??
Nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si tu computadora está apagada de nada sirve que la ip esté actualizada. Tiene cierta lógica dejar un servidor encendido 24/7, si un servidor está apagado no sirve.

Comment: ok. Si mi PC esta apagado y no me actualiza la ip tendré que ver de otra forma como enviar datos desde mi web a mi modulo a menos que exista algún programa que me actualice la ip pero que no este en mi pc, ya que el objetivo de mi proyecto es que el modulo que funcionando autonomamente

Comment: Eso de "actualizar una IP" suena un poco exagerado, una vez que un router tipo ADSL obtiene una IP externa, el arrendamiento en la LAN puede ser configurado en periodos que van desde 1 minuto a una semana, e incluso, en algunos modelos puede ser permanente (mientras no se apague el router, claro). También es posible que el propio router actualice la noip. Claro que una ip actualizada no sirve de nada si el equipo en cuestión está apagado.

Comment: @JuanJoseQuirozMoreno Si esto responde a tu pregunta, por favor considerá aceptarla. De lo contrario, sería bueno que aclares qué estaría faltando... Por ejemplo, leyendo tu otra pregunta, estás actualizando la IP desde la PC pero el Arduino está siempre conectado? Aclarar ese tipo de cosas ayudaría muchísimo a poder responder.