# Esconder datos de URL

Tags: php

Hola compañeros necesito poder esconder la información que envió por URL.
He buscado códigos que me ayuden hacerlo pero no he tenido buenos resultados.
El Código es:

```
<?php 
include("obtenerdatos.php");
$user=$_POST['usuario'];
$pass=$_POST['contrasena'];
$ok = 0;
$objeto = new SQLConector;
$lista = $objeto->MostrarUsuario();

for($i =0; $i<count($lista); $i++){
    if($user==$lista[$i]['usuario'] and $pass==$lista[$i]['password']){
        $ok=1; 
        header("Location:bienvenido.php?user=".$user); 
    }   
}
if ($ok==0){
header("Location:invalido.php");
}
?>
```

Lo que deseo esconder es el re direccionamiento a **header("Location:bienvenido.php?user=".$user)** ya que a ese archivo le envió información y es vistaenla URL.
Cualquier ayuda me sera de utilidad Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres esconder el user no envíes los datos a través de la url, puedes usar una sesión para almacenar la variable user, y recuperarla en tu página **bienvenido.php**, algo así:

```
<?php 
include("obtenerdatos.php");

session_start();

$user=$_POST['usuario'];
$pass=$_POST['contrasena'];
$ok = 0;
$objeto = new SQLConector;
$lista = $objeto->MostrarUsuario();

for($i =0; $i<count($lista); $i++){
    if($user==$lista[$i]['usuario'] and $pass==$lista[$i]['password']){
        $ok=1; 
        $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
        header("Location:bienvenido.php"); 
    }   
}
if ($ok==0){
  header("Location:invalido.php");
}
?>
```

Y en tu página **bienvenido.php** la puedes recuperar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero el código de recepcion no me funcionaba y le agregue abrir la sesión nuevamente mediante un session_start("user"); de todos modos gracias!!

Comment: Si tienes razón me faltó esa parte, estoy desde un celular y no me di cuenta, ahora edito la respuesta. Te sirvió esta respuesta?

Comment: @JuanJoseQuirozMoreno Si crees que esto es una solución a tu problema, por favor considerá [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) haciendo click en el tilde a la izquierda (ambos se benefician). -Y lo mismo aplica en [preguntas que hayas hecho antes](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20545/127).

Comment: Juan Pinzón , si me sirvió gracias.